# Implement Comparable for generic Linked List for different classes

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

First of all: I'm not trying to re-invent the wheel, this is for purpose of study.

I'm quite a newbie in [java](/questions/tagged/java) world so be patient.

My aim is to build a public class to manage linked list with sorted insertion.

What I did so far (that is working) is:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

import package_Car.SortTypes;

class Node<E>
{
    E data;
    Node<E> next;

    Node(E data, Node<E> node)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = node;
    }

    public Node<E> getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }
}

public class SortedInsertionLinkedList<E> implements Iterable<Node<E>>
{
    Node<E> root;
    Sort_Types sort;

    final class LinkedListIterator implements Iterator<Node<E>>
    {
        private Node<E> cursor;

        LinkedListIterator(Node<E> root)
        {
            cursor = new Node<E>(null, null);
            cursor = root;
        }

        public boolean hasNext()
        {       
            return cursor != null;
        }

        public Node<E> next()
        {
            Node<E> retVal = cursor;

            if (hasNext())
            {
                cursor = retVal.getNext();
            }

            return retVal;      
        }
    }   

    public Iterator<Node<E>> iterator()
    {
        return new LinkedListIterator(root);
    }

    public SortedInsertionLinkedList(Sort_Types sort)
    {
        root = null;
        this.sort = sort;
    }

    public void insert(E item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (root == null)
            {
                root = new Node<E>(item, null);
            }
            else
            {
                Node<E> currNode = root;
                Node<E> prevNode = null;

                for (Node<E> currListNode : this) 
                {
                    if (sort.compareTo(currListNode.data, item) < 0)
                    {
                        prevNode = currListNode;
                        currNode = currListNode.next;
                    }
                }

                Node<E> t = new Node<E>(item, currNode);

                if (prevNode == null)
                    root = t;
                else
                    prevNode.next = t;

            }
        }
    }

    public void print()
    {
        for (Node<E> currNode : this)
        {
            System.out.print(currNode.data + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public boolean find(E x)
    {
        for (Node<E> currNode : this)
        {
            int c = sort.compareTo(currNode.data, x);

            if (c == 0)
                return true;
            if (c > 0)
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void delete(E x)
    {
        Node<E> prevNode = null;
        for (Node<E> currNode : this)
        {
            int c = sort.compareTo(currNode.data, x);
            if (c == 0)
            {
                if (currNode == root)
                {
                    root = currNode.next;
                }
                else
                {
                    prevNode.next = currNode.next;
                }

                return;
            }
            if (c > 0)
                return;

            prevNode = currNode;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I added to my class a private field that define which type of sort have to be used to compare linked list Nodes. This sort type is a enum

```
public enum Sort_Types
{
    SORT_BY_NAME
    {
        public int compareTo(Object o1, Object o2)
        {
            Car item1 = (Car) o1;
            Car item2 = (Car) o2;

            return item1.nome.compareTo(item2.nome);
        }
    },
    SORT_BY_PRICE
    {
        public int compareTo(Object o1, Object o2)
        {
            Car item1 = (Car) o1;
            Car item2 = (Car) o2;

            return Double.compare(item1.prezzo, item2.prezzo);
        }
    },
    SORT_BY_GAIN
    {
        public int compareTo(Object o1, Object o2)
        {
            double gain1;
            double gain2;

            if (o1 instanceof CarSpecificInterface)
            {
                CarSpecificInterface dummy = (CarSpecificInterface) o1;
                gain1 = dummy.gain();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

            if (o2 instanceof CarSpecificInterface)
            {
                CarSpecificInterface dummy = (CarSpecificInterface) o2;
                gain2 = dummy.gain();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

            return Double.compare(gain2, gain1);
        }
    },
    SORT_BY_URGENCY
    {
        public int compareTo(Object o1, Object o2)
        {
            double urgency1;
            double urgency2;

            if (o1 instanceof CarSpecificInterface)
            {
                CarSpecificInterface dummy = (CarSpecificInterface) o1;
                urgency1 = dummy.urgency();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }

            if (o2 instanceof CarSpecificInterface)
            {
                CarSpecificInterface dummy = (CarSpecificInterface) o2;
                urgency2 = dummy.urgency();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }        

            return Double.compare(urgency2, urgency1);
        }
    };

    public abstract int compareTo(Object o1, Object o2);
}
```

Why I did that? Because of class that can be used to instatiate the linked list are 3:

1. `Car`
2. `New_Car` that `extends Car`
3. `Used_Car` that `extends Car`

`New_Car` and `Used_Car` classes implements an interface

```
public interface Car_Specific_Interface
{
    public double gain();
    public double urgency();
}
```

So I can use my linked list for type Car that can accept (obviously) SubClasses

```
Sorted_Linked_List<Car> carsSortedByName;
Sorted_Linked_List<Car> carSortedByGain;
Sorted_Linked_List<Car> carSortedByUrgency;

public DB_Mng()
{
    carsSortedByName = new Sorted_Linked_List<>(Sort_Types.SORT_BY_NAME);
    carSortedByGain = new Sorted_Linked_List<>(Sort_Types.SORT_BY_GAIN);
    carSortedByGain = new Sorted_Linked_List<>(Sort_Types.SORT_BY_URGENCY);
}
```

So, to sum up: I have a *generic linked list with sorted insertion* that can accept different classes and can be sorted by specific field or methods.

What I'd like to understand is if there is a way to do that changing classes hierarchy "simply" implementing `Comparable` interface.

Comment: Do not use and enum to implement a strategy pattern.  Using an enum to identify the strategy makes sense; perhaps put the implementation of each sort as the value and use the enum as the key.

Comment: @DwB Ok, but how can be that used in a generic Linked List? Each node has reference only for Super class `Car`. How can refer to the correct compare method? Obviously I'd prefer to avoid using a `switch` inside `insert` method based on `sort type`.

Comment: Unrelated: "_" is solely for SOME_CONSTANT. Dont use it for other names. And variable names go camelCase in Java. So you go `carsSortedByName` instead of `List_Car_Sort_name`.

Comment: @GhostCat Ths, I'll keeep it in mind. My (solid)  [tag:c] background have a hand in... ;)

Comment: @LPs You better do. You see, Underbars_in_the_wrong_places cause eye cancer and brain damage to experienced Java programmers, and for sure you don't intent to hurt anybody here, right? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one is to understand java generics.
Specifically,
java generics are a compile time feature;
they are in no way a java implementation of c++ templates.

You can not create a "fully general" sorted-on-insert list because Object does not implement any comparison functionality.

You can create a sorted-on-insert list of elements that implement some known interface or which extend a specific class.

Comment: I actually like the lambda answer, but I don't like lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to fully step back here. With Java8 and lambdas and streams one really does things differently in 2017. Or well, since years.

I recommend you looking into this [presentation](http://2014.java-forum-stuttgart.de/_data/E4_2014.pdf) from the Java Forum Stuttgart 2014. A few starting words in German, but the rest is all code, and easy to grasp.

Thing is: you want to write code like:

```
collection .sort(
  Comparator
  .comparing(Person::getName)
  .reversed()
  .thenComparing(Person::getId)
);
```

and use lambdas / method references - instead of writing all that "manual boilerplate" code to access member fields for example.

Comment: I already know Comparator class (not so much about Lambdas), but as I wrote is something I'm doing as case study to understand better hierarchy and generic classes. BTW thank you for the linked doc. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

If both `NewCar` and `UsedCar` are implementing `Car_Specific_Interface` you can just check interface in your comparators, like:

```
        if (o1 instanceof Car_Specific_Interface)
        {
            Car_Specific_Interface dummy = (Car_Specific_Interface) o1;
            gain1 = dummy.gain();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
```

also you can make you compare function more complex to support `Comparable` and `Comparator`. For example:

```
private int compareItems(E firstItem, E secondItem) {
    if (sort == null) {
        if (firstItem instanceof Comparable && secondItem instanceof Comparable) {
            return ((Comparable)firstItem).compareTo(secondItem);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to compare");
        }
    } 
    return sort.compareTo(firstItem, secondItem);
}
```

Comment: Good catch for the first suggestion about interface: I didn't see that. About the second I need some time to understand better the idea... ;) +1 I updated the question code considering the interface suggestion.